# Is there an allusion to Genesis 3:7 in Luke 24:31?

Tags: genesis, luke, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, eucharist

As I was thinking about the Lord's supper, and possible connections between "taking" and "eating" in Matthew 26:26 and Genesis 3:6, another possible connection occured to me. Towards the end of Luke, in the story about Jesus on the road to Emmaus, we read:

> When he was at the table with them, he took bread, gave thanks, broke it and began to give it to them. Then **their eyes were opened** and they recognized him, and he disappeared from their sight.
>
> <sup>Luke 24:30-31 (NIV emphasis mine)</sup>

This reminded me perhaps of Genesis 3:6-7:

> When the woman saw that the fruit of the tree was good for food and pleasing to the eye, and also desirable for gaining wisdom, she took some and ate it. She also gave some to her husband, who was with her, and he ate it. Then **the eyes of both of them were opened**, and they realized they were naked; so they sewed fig leaves together and made coverings for themselves.

However, when I did a search on "eyes" and "opened" it seems like not an uncommon metaphor. At least there were enough other occurrences to cast doubt that this is a clear allusion. However, it's not so common that I would dismiss it out of hand either. Are there other reasons to think that Luke might be making an allusion to Genesis 3:7 here?

Comment: Did you find other NT usages? “Eyes” get used pretty frequently in Hebrew, metaphorically and otherwise, including “opened”, but I don’t know how common it is in Greek *sans* allusion to the HB/LXX. (Or maybe just Hebraic influence, which seems likely even if there is no allusion to a particular text).

Comment: off the cuff I would say 'no' and a quick scan of Beale/ Carson seems to bear that out :D

Comment: @Susan The other NT usages are in John 9, Mark 8, and Matthew 9, 20 - all referring to Jesus healing physical blindness (though with obvious symbolism, especially in John 9). And then there are three in Acts: an odd reference in 9:8 to Saul being blind ("although his eyes were opened, he saw nothing"), in 9:40 when Peter raises Tabitha, and then probably the only other directly metaphorical reference in the NT in 26:18 where Paul describes his commission to the Gentiles - that he might "open their eyes, so they may turn from darkness to light."

Comment: For what it’s worth....from what I can tell all of the others use ἀνοίγω; only Luke 24:31 uses διανοίγω (considerably less common, always - in the NT - metaphorical - womb, mind, scriptures, etc.) with ὀφθαλμοὶ, same as LXX Gen 3:6,7. And in the LXX that phrase in its passive form is limited to Gen 3. No idea if that’s meaningful, but that’s all I have to contribute. :-)

Comment: Using TLG, I tried to find examples outside GNT, LXX and Patristics but didn't find any. Some form of it occurs over 30 times in LXX which suggests that it was a greek form of a Hebrew idiom. The lxx samples: Gen. 3:5, Gen. 3:7, Gen. 21:19, Judg. 11:35, 1Kings 8:29, 1Kings 8:52, 2Kings 4:35, 2Kings 6:17, 2Kings 6:20, 2Kings 19:16, 2Chr. 6:20, 2Chr. 6:40, 2Chr. 7:15, Neh. 1:6, Tob. 2:10, Tob. 11:7, Prov. 20:13, Job 27:19, Zech. 12:4, Is. 35:5, Is. 42:7, Bar. 2:17, Dan. 9:18

Comment: By far the most interesting citation I found was greek fragment of 1Ehoch 106:2. καὶ ὅτε ἀνέῳξεν τοὺς ὀφθαλμούς, ἔλαμψεν ἡ οἰκία ὡσεὶ ἥλιος. **Methuselah took a wife for his son Lamech .... And when he opened his eyes, he lighted up the whole house like the sun, and the whole house was very bright.**  http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/boe/boe110.htm

Comment: Just to clarify, the 30x in the LXX C.Stirling Bartholomew has identified are mostly using ἀνοίγω rather than the prefixed διανοίγω. The expression using the later occurs 6 times, but the passive form (like your Luke example) occurs only in Genesis 3. But yes, both Hebraisms/LXXisms from פקח עינים. Lukan LXXisms seem to be a particular thing...

Comment: @Susan, Yes, I was looking for evidence with for both verbs. The only early use of διανοίγω with ὀφθαλμοὺς I found using TLG is cited in LSJ under διανοίγω. Plato Phil., Lysis 210a. It is **not** and idiom for cognitive change of state. There is a 1BC use of οὺς ὀφθαλμοὺς ἀνοίξας in Dionysius Halicarnassensis Hist 20.5.3 which is also literal forcing open the eyes, not the metaphor. So the metaphor appears to be Hebraic but the heavyweights on b-greek haven't really answered my question.

Comment: While it doesn't directly address your question, the following article is related to your topic. LUKE'S USE OF THE JEWISH SCRIPTURES IN THE TEXT OF LUKE 24 IN CODEX BEZAE Jenny Read-Heimerdinger and Josep Rius-Camps. http://www.ilfilo.org/Rius%20Camps/Oulammaous.pdf. I used another work by these authors while doing my translation of Codex Bezae in Acts.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, there is likely an allusion here.

I had trouble finding many commentators who discuss even the possibility of an allusion. In fact, the sole mention I could find came from Luke Timothy Johnson's volume on Luke in the *Sacra Pagina* series. Almost in passing he writes:

> The phrase echoes the biblical language used of Adam and Eve in Gen 3:7, "the eyes of the two were opened and they recognized that they were naked."

However, there is an article in the *Journal of the Evangelical Society* Volum 53(4), where Dane Ortlund addresses the very question. The article is titled, '["And Their Eyes Were Opened, and They Knew": An Inter-canonical Note on Luke 24:31](http://www.etsjets.org/files/JETS-PDFs/53/53-4/JETS_53-4_717-728_Ortlund.pdf).'

He begins by surveying what he considers to be the neglect of attention to the allusion, listing a large number of commentaries, monographs, and theologies that make no mention of the topic. Particularly he finds the lack of mention in Pao and Schnabel's chapter on Luke in Carson and Beale's *Commentary on the New Testament Use of the Old Testament* to be a serious lacuna.

However, he mentions three scholars who mention the allusion: the previously mentioned statement in L.T. Johnson's volume, a couple of remarks in some of N.T. Wright's works (e.g. on p. 652 in *The Resurrection of the Son of God*), and in a work by Arthur Just titled *The Ongoing Feast: Table Fellowship and Eschatology at Emmaus*.

Having surveyed the literature he goes on to build his argument for an allusion along four lines: 1) linguistic, 2) narratival, 3) interpretive, and 4) redemptive-history.

*Linguistic*
Ortlund notes as some have mentioned in comments above that the word translated "opened" - διανοίγω - in Luke 24:31 is rare within the New Testament. In fact, in application to eyes being opened, this is its sole use. Moreover, this is the same word used in the LXX in Genesis 3:7. Second, though, Ortlund extends the connection beyond eyes being opened, to the part of recognition noting that ἐπιγινώσκω ("recognized") in Luke and γινώσκω ("realized") share the same γινωσκω root.

*Narratival*
In terms of narrative, Ortlund makes a number of connections between the two accounts: some more convincing than others. At the most basic narratival level, though, is the consuming of food, followed by the opening of the eyes, followed finally by the profound new recognition of a spiritual reality.

*Interpretive*
Ortlund states, "A third reason for suspecting an inter-canonical allusion in Luke 24:31 is the explanatory power it provides to the flow of Luke 24 as a whole." Here he argues that the disciples are kept from recognizing Jesus so that the critical point of recognition is in the breaking and eating of bread. This allows it to match up with the Genesis narrative in which also the critical point of recognition is in the eating.

*Redemptive-Historical*
Finally, Ortlund supports the allusion along redemptive-historical grounds, suggesting that Luke's concern is to highlight the new creation. Similarly, Wright in his brief treatment of the passage in *The Resurrection of the Son of God* points out that the Genesis 3 eating is the first meal of the original creation, the Luke 24 passage the first meal of the new creation.